# Spring Integration Test Loading Annotated Beans

Tags: java, spring-boot, integration-testing, junit4

For some reason, my DAO is not loaded when I use @ComponentScan alone.

My DAO:

```
@Repository
public class MyDAO{
  @Autowire
  private Datasource ds;
}
```

My Config class (just overrides datasource bean with an embedded DB):

```
@Configuration
public class TestConfig extends AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public Datasource getDatasource() throws Exception{...}
```

My Test Class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestConfig.class})
@ComponentScan
public class MyDAOTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyDAO target;
```

My understanding is that @ComponentScan should be able to find MyDAO and load it (the datasource in TestConfig class is loaded just fine). However, MyDAO is not being loaded. I'm getting "org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.acme.dao.MyDAO] found for dependency." I also tried specifying packages in the @ComponentScan such as com.acme or com.acme.dao.

When I include MyDAO.class as one of the classes in @ContextConfiguration, it works fine. However, I don't want to list all of the classes for my integration tests...

Comment: `@ComponentScan` belongs on the `@Configuration` class, not the `@ContextConfiguration` class. cf http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html

Comment: @DonBottstein Ok, So how do I load all my annotated beans with just overriding the datasource for my integration tests?

Comment: @DonBottstein Ok, I think I got it. I added (at)ComponentScan to my TestConfig.class, and it appears to be working now. thanks.

Comment: See my answer below. This is how I use a main config class with any overrides in a test config class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following setup will load default beans from AppConfig, while overriding any beans specified in TestConfig. TestConfig can be a nested class (within MyDAOTest) as long as it is declared static.

```
@ContextConfiguration( classes = TestConfig.class )
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class MyDAOTest {
    ...
}

@Import(AppConfig.class)
public class TestConfig {
    @Bean public Datasource getDatasource() throws Exception {...}
}

@Configuration
@ComponentScan( basePackages = {"com.acme"})
public class AppConfig {
    ....
}
```